# Remove space at the left side of listing <li>

Tags: html, css

I did spend multiple hour just to remove the space in front of the listing. But still, I can't find what to edit/add. Please help.

Here my
http://jsfiddle.net/tFQCS/2

```
#dropdown {    
position:absolute;
display:none;
border:1px solid #A4A4A4;
width:80px;
height:285px;
overflow:auto;
background:#f9f9f9;
text-align:center;
list-style-type:none;
}
#dropdown ul {
margin:0px;
height:5px;
padding:0px;
background:#f9f9f9;
list-style-type:none;
}
#dropdown ul li {
height:5px;
list-style:none;
}
#dropdown li:hover { 
background:#ccc; 
cursor:pointer; 
}
```

As you can see, on the result panel, when you click on the text input, it will display a list, but the text is not centralize because of the space in front of the text. How can i remove it, so that my text will be centralize.

Secondly, as you can see there's a gap between the text input (box) and the listing. how can I display the listing just below the box without any space.

Thanks.

Comment: I did not see the list

Comment: the code in your fiddle doesnt seem to work here - the dropdown never appears. Tried in chrome and firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any list shown when i click on the text input, however the browser itself contains some margin or padding for some elements like body, ul and li...

```
body, ul, li {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have take a look on your fiddle

adding

```
padding: 0;
```

to **ul** solved your problem. i removes left space.

```
ul
{
list-style-type: none;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
}
```